# lookup site user property sharepoint Designer 2010? How to get full name? Which Property to use?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow-activity

I have heard so much about this [SPD activity](https://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lookup%20user%20info&referringTitle=Home).I 'm on SP 2010
I have installed it but i can't get a full name of a user by using Name Property.
When i use Name property is till get DOMAINName\username.

What property to use when on SP 2010 for it to work.

Cheers
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The ImnName property will return the full name when using the Lookup site user property Workflow action.

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayName` field contains the Full User name!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But I tested with DisplayName 
I get error:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. 
Parameter name: Property not found.

But it doesn't work
Cheers

Comment: Try concatenating `FirstName` and `LastName` fields ?

Comment: Thanks but can you elaborate more?When i use FirstName and Lastname as properties i did get error.
Cheers

Comment: Can you post some code in the Question, so I can see how are you trying !

Comment: Thanks Arsalan I figured it out.You can't use the DisplayName as a lookup property but return the field as DisplayName

Comment: Okay good, please post your code as answer and mark it as correct !